# How to know which class raised a NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby

I don't want to raise a NoMethodError at a certain place but only for a certain class (ex. NilClass).

Ex.

```
begin
  maybe_nil_maybe_not_nil = nil
  maybe_nil_maybe_not_nil.x
rescure NoMethodError => ex
  raise unless ex.class_which_raised == NilClass
end
```

I now do this based on the to_s of the exception but messages are different when you don't expect it for .id, .product and maybe others. It would be better to do this based on metadata/parameters. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, depending on what you're doing and how you feel about re-opening classes, another option is to override method_missing on your class, e.g.:

```
class NilClass
  alias method_missing old_method_missing
  def method_missing(m_sym, *args, &block)
    old_method_missing m_sym, *args, &block
    log_that_you_had_a_missing_method_call
  end
end
```

This is kind of dirty, but sometimes you don't have control over all of the callers of the method, if you're dealing with e.g. a library. I would make sure to add a lot of comments about why you're monkey patching your class, since the potential for unintended side effects is huge here.

I would recommend, barring any TOCTOU issues, if you possibly can, going with Matt von Rohr's solution of looking before you leap.

Comment: This is a solution for my problem. But Matt von Rohr's answer sounds safer :)

Answer (score 4):

Using exceptions for control flow is usually a bad idea. What would happen if the method you called raised a `NoMethodError` itself? (It would get swallowed by your rescue block)

You're better off using `respond_to?`

```
raise 'this is bad' if object.nil?

if object.respond_to?(:x)
  object.x
end
```

Comment: what happend if the object doesn't implement respond_to? properly ?

Comment: respond_to? is declared for the class Object. Unless your working with objects of type BasicObject or Objects coming from another ruby-meta-programming-stunt it will work as expected. Besides: why should those objects lie to you? ;)

Comment: This is a much cleaner approach. Think about it: You're testing for nil by sending it a message, seeing if the receiver bounces the message, and only then trying to see if the object that bounced the message is nil. Why not just test for nil in the first place if that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Only because ruby programmer like ruby-meta-programming and as `define_method` and `respond_to` are not linked, therefore there is no guaranty than they work as expected. Someone said (murphy?) "if something can go wrong, it will". However you can also survive on the assumption than respond_to? doesn't lie. Depends on your "environment"

Comment: @mb14: What are you talking about? If you do `define_method(:foo) {puts "Brilliant name, genius"}`, then `obj.respond_to? :foo` will be true.

Comment: @chuck My mistake, I meant `missing_method` not `define_method`.